# Java concurrency with queues

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

What I am trying to do is basically kick off new threads, add them to a queue, and than execute the rest of the code when they are dequeued. I'm not sure what the best way to add them to a queue, and how I can pause a thread at a point and notify them when they are dequeued.  I haven't really done too much concurrent programming in Java before.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), basically creating a pool of threads according to multiple customizable rules.

And to be sure that all threads have done their respective job before your process goes on the remaining code, you just have to call `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `awaitTermination` method preceded by an eventual `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `shutdown` method.

You could also send a `notify`/`notifyAll` after the call to `awaitTermination` in order to wake up some other result-dependent threads.

A sample is written in the [`ExecutorService` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (implemented by `ThreadPoolExecutor`).

Answer (score 1):

`wait()` and `notify()` can be used for this, as such:

```
class QueuedThread extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean wait = true; //volatile because otherwise the thread running run() might cache this value and run into an endless loop.

    public void deQueue() {
        synchronized(this) {
            wait = false;
            this.notify();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            while (wait) { //You need this extra mechanism because wait() can come out randomly, so it's a safe-guard against that (so you NEED to have called deQueue() to continue executing).
                this.wait();
            }
        }
    //REST OF RUN METHOD HERE
    }
}
```

Just call `queuedThread.deQueue()` when it should be de-queued.

Comment: why are you synchronizing on wait?  that is very wrong.  you shouldnt be syncing on a field that woukd change

Comment: @JohnVint I normally use specific locks but thought I'd simplify. You are right, fixed code.